# change height of TableViewHeader and included UILabel after button click

Tags: swift, uitableview, header, constraints, uilabel

When I want to set a new long status by pressing the button, my profileStatusLabel height and TableViewHeader height as well don't change.

P.S. sorry about my English, if there are some mistakes

[image]

**ProfileHeaderView: UIView
**

```
import UIKit

...
        
    private lazy var profileStatusLabel: UILabel = {
        let profileStatusLabel = UILabel()
        profileStatusLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        profileStatusLabel.text = "Looking for a big, young, good looking, able to cook female gorilla"
        profileStatusLabel.textColor = .gray
        profileStatusLabel.font = profileNameLabel.font.withSize(14)
        profileStatusLabel.textAlignment = .left
        profileStatusLabel.sizeToFit()
        profileStatusLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return profileStatusLabel
    }()
    
    private lazy var setStatusButton: UIButton = {
        let setStatusButton = UIButton()
        setStatusButton.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        setStatusButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        setStatusButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)
        setStatusButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        setStatusButton.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        setStatusButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        setStatusButton.setTitle("Set status", for: .normal)
        setStatusButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        setStatusButton.titleLabel?.font = setStatusButton.titleLabel?.font.withSize(14)
        setStatusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        setStatusButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return setStatusButton
    }()
        
    private lazy var statusText: String = {
        return statusText
    }()
        
    private func setupView() {
        addSubview(profileImageView)
        addSubview(profileNameLabel)
        addSubview(profileStatusLabel)
        addSubview(statusTextField)
        addSubview(setStatusButton)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            profileNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 27),
            profileNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            profileNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            profileNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 30),
            
            profileStatusLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            profileStatusLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            profileStatusLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            profileStatusLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 49),
            
            statusTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileStatusLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            statusTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            statusTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            statusTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            
            setStatusButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            setStatusButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            setStatusButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            setStatusButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: setStatusButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
        ])
    }
        
    @objc private func statusTextChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        statusText = statusTextField.text!
    }
    
    @objc private func buttonAction() {
        guard statusTextField.text != nil else {
            print("Text the status before press the button")
            return
        }
        profileStatusLabel.text = statusText
        profileStatusLabel.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .systemGray4
        setupView()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

**MyCustomHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView
**

```
import UIKit

class MyCustomHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    var profileHeaderView = ProfileHeaderView()
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configureContents()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func configureContents() {
        contentView.addSubview(profileHeaderView)
        profileHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileHeaderView.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileHeaderView.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileHeaderView.widthAnchor),
            contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileHeaderView.heightAnchor),
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileHeaderView.topAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

**ProfileViewController
**

```
import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    let postList = [robberyPost, eatingPost, elephantPost, camelPost]

    var profileTableView = UITableView()
    let myCustomHeader = MyCustomHeader()
    
    let headerID = "headerId"
    let headerID2 = "headerId2"
    let cellID = "cellId"
    let collectionCellID = "collectionCellId"
    
...
        
    func setupTableView() {
        profileTableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        profileTableView.register(PhotosTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: PhotosTableViewCell.cellID)
        profileTableView.register(PostTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: PostTableViewCell.cellID)
        profileTableView.delegate = self
        profileTableView.dataSource = self
        profileTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(profileTableView)
    }
    
    func setupMyCustomHeader() {
        profileTableView.register(MyCustomHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: headerID)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            profileTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            profileTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            profileTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
        
    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        setupTableView()
        setupMyCustomHeader()
        setupConstraints()
    }
}

extension ProfileViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
...

    // MARK: - Table view delegate
    
...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
        }

        if section == 0 {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        } else {
            return 50
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 0 {

            let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerID) as! MyCustomHeader
            let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(profileImageViewClicked(_ :)))
            tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
            tapRecognizer.delegate = self
            header.profileHeaderView.profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            header.profileHeaderView.profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
            return header
        } else {
            let header2 = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerID2) as! OneMoreCustomHeader
            return header2
        }
    }
...
    
}
```

Probably I should use updateConstraints() function, but can't find the right way.
I added this code to buttonAction, buy it doesn't work

```
        profileStatusLabel.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: add text height to header view height by getting height from string and then reload tableview data to update height on set status button also just give left right and top to status label not give height

Answer (score 0):

Any time you change the height of a table view element - cell, section header or footer view, etc - you must tell the table view to re-layout its elements.

This is commonly done with a `closure`.

For example, you would add this property to your custom header view class:

```
// closure so table layout can be updated
var contentChanged: (() -> ())?
```

and then set that closure in `viewForHeaderInSection`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {

        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerID) as! MyCustomHeader
        
        // set the closure
        header.contentChanged = {
            // tell the table view to re-layout itself so the header height can be changed
            tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil)
        }
        
        return header
        
    } else {
        
        let header2 = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerID2) as! OneMoreCustomHeader
        return header2
        
    }
}
```

and when you tap the "Set status" button to update the `profileStatusLabel`, you would use the closure to "call back" to the controller:

```
contentChanged?()
```

With the code you posted, you are embedding `ProfileHeaderView` in `MyCustomHeader`, which complicates things a little because you will need a closure in `MyCustomHeader` that works with another closure in `ProfileHeaderView`.

There really is no need to do that -- you can put all of your UI elements directly in `MyCustomHeader` to avoid that issue.

Here is a complete, runnable example. I changed your `MyCustomHeader` as described... as well as added some other code that you will probably end up needing (see the comments):

```
class MyCustomHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    // closure to inform the controller the status text changed
    //  so we can update the data and
    //  so the table layout can be updated
    var contentChanged: ((String) -> ())?
    
    //  presumably, we'll be setting the statusText and the name from a dataSource
    public var statusText: String = "" {
        didSet {
            profileStatusLabel.text = statusText
        }
    }

    public var name: String = "" {
        didSet {
            profileNameLabel.text = name
        }
    }
    
    private lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "person.crop.circle") {
            v.image = img
        }
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    private lazy var profileNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let profileStatusLabel = UILabel()
        profileStatusLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        profileStatusLabel.text = ""
        profileStatusLabel.textColor = .black
        profileStatusLabel.textAlignment = .left
        profileStatusLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return profileStatusLabel
    }()
    
    private lazy var profileStatusLabel: UILabel = {
        let profileStatusLabel = UILabel()
        profileStatusLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        profileStatusLabel.text = ""
        profileStatusLabel.textColor = .gray
        profileStatusLabel.textAlignment = .left
        profileStatusLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return profileStatusLabel
    }()
    
    private lazy var setStatusButton: UIButton = {
        let setStatusButton = UIButton()
        setStatusButton.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        setStatusButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        setStatusButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)
        setStatusButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        setStatusButton.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        setStatusButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        setStatusButton.setTitle("Set status", for: .normal)
        setStatusButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        setStatusButton.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        setStatusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        setStatusButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return setStatusButton
    }()
    
    private lazy var statusTextField: UITextField = {
        let statusTextField = UITextField()
        statusTextField.text = ""
        statusTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        statusTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        statusTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return statusTextField
    }()
    
    private func setupView() {
        contentView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(profileNameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(profileStatusLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(statusTextField)
        contentView.addSubview(setStatusButton)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            profileImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),
            profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.widthAnchor),
            
            profileNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 27),
            profileNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            profileNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            profileNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            
            profileStatusLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            profileStatusLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            profileStatusLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            profileStatusLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 49),
            
            statusTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileStatusLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            statusTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            statusTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            statusTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            
            setStatusButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            setStatusButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            setStatusButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            setStatusButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: setStatusButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            
        ])
    }
    
    @objc private func buttonAction() {
        guard let stText = statusTextField.text else {
            print("Text the status before press the button")
            return
        }
        statusTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        
        // update statusText property
        //  which will also set the text in the label
        statusText = stText
        
        // call the closure, passing back the new text
        contentChanged?(stText)
    }
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.backgroundColor = .systemGray4
        setupView()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    // presumably, this will be loaded from saved data, along with the rest of the table data
    var dataSourceStatusText: String = "Looking for a big, young, good looking, able to cook female gorilla"
    
    var profileTableView = UITableView()
    
    let headerID = "headerId"
    let cellID = "cellId"
    
    func setupTableView() {
        profileTableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        profileTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
        profileTableView.delegate = self
        profileTableView.dataSource = self
        profileTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(profileTableView)
    }
    
    func setupMyCustomHeader() {
        profileTableView.register(MyCustomHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: headerID)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            profileTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            profileTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            profileTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        setupTableView()
        setupMyCustomHeader()
        setupConstraints()
    }
}

extension ProfileViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // let's use 10 sections each with 5 rows so we can scroll the header out-of-view
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)
        c.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return c
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
        }
        if section == 0 {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        } else {
            return 50
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 0 {

            let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerID) as! MyCustomHeader

            header.name = "@KillaGorilla"
            header.statusText = dataSourceStatusText

            // set the closure
            header.contentChanged = { [weak self] newStatus in
                guard let self = self else { return }

                // update the status text (probably also saving it somewhere?)
                //  if we don't do this, and the section header scrolls out of view,
                //  the *original* status text will be shown
                self.dataSourceStatusText = newStatus

                // tell the table view to re-layout itself so the header height can be changed
                tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil)
            }

            return header
            
        } else {
            
            // this would be your other section header view
            //  for now, let's just use a label
            let v = UILabel()
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            v.text = "Section Header: \(section)"
            return v
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Give that a try.